# What does '%TYPE' mean following a parameter in procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to PL/SQL and tried searching for this online with no avail - I would appreciate any help!

I am looking at a procedure that is something along the lines of this:

```
PROCEDURE pProcedureOne
(pDateOne              DATE,
 pDateTwo              tableA.DateTwo%TYPE,
 pDateThree            tableB.DateThree%TYPE,
 pTypeOne              tableC.TypeOne%TYPE,
 pTestId               tableD.TestIdentifier%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
 pShouldChange BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
IS
```

What does `'%TYPE'` keyword mean in this context?

Comment: This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/TYPE-attribute.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableA.DateTwo%TYPE` means "the data type of the `DateTwo` column in the `tableA` table".  You'll see this referred to as an "anchored type" in documentation.

Using anchored types is quite useful for a couple of reasons

1. If the data type of the table changes, the code automatically gets compiled with the new data type.  This eliminates the issue where, say, a `varchar2(100)` column in a table gets modified later to allow `varchar2(255)` and you have to look through dozens or hundreds of methods that reference that column to make sure that their local variables are updated to be long enough.
2. It documents what data you expect to be passed in to a procedure or for a local variable to reference.  In large systems, you generally have at least a few concepts that have very similar names but that represent slightly different concepts.  If you look at a procedure that has a parameter `tableA.DateTwo%TYPE`, that can be very useful information if there is a different `DateTwoPrime` column that represents a slightly different date.

Answer (score 1):

%TYPE means the field type does not have to be defined because it is going to inherit it from the field's type.

So pDateTwo doesn't require its own type definition because it will have to same type as             tableA.DateTwo.

Answer (score 1):

It means to use the data type of the table.column you are referencing. So for example, if tableC.TypeOne is VARCHAR2(10), then that is the datatype assigned to pTypeOne.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the data type of, for example, `pDateTwo` is to be the same as the data type of `tableA.DateTwo`.